# "Quote" button breaks formatting

Tags: support, bug, code-formatting, blockquote

I was editing [this question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/what-does-%D0%AF-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-mean) on russian.SE where the OP was asking about the meaning of a Russian poem.  As the poem itself wasn't formatted properly, I wanted to fix the line breaks to make it easier to read.  In the process of doing so, I essentially broke the poem down with the line breaks and added `<br/>`, so that it would look like so:

```
Line 1<br/>
Line 2<br/>
Line 3<br/>
Line 4<br/>
...
```

Then I highlighted the whole poem and clicked the "blockquote" button.  I expected the block to just be indented with `>`, however besides that, all line breaks were deleted and the text became

```
> Line 1<br/> Line 2<br/> Line 3<br/>Line 4<br/>
```

While this produces the output I want, it's still messing up the original text making it more difficult for anyone who may want to edit the post later.  I ended up having to do this manually for each of the lines.

I don't think changing the content on click of a formatting button is the right behaviour.

Comment: _Please_ use two spaces rather than `<br/>` it makes everyones' life a lot easier as they don't have to go through removing them again...

Comment: Cool! I never realised that two spaces are equivalent to `<br/>`.  I re-edited the post with the poem to replace all `<br/>` with two spaces.  However this doesn't solve the original problem - the line breaks are still deleted when I click "blockquote" button.

Comment: @ben but in such case it's turned to `> Line 1   Line 2   Line 3   Line 4` which is even worse as the line breaks are gone.

Comment: Even though you can just add two spaces at the end of each line as @ben suggested (and that’s the preferred way), this often bothers me when wanting to quote before correcting, so +1 to that.

Comment: I wasn't answering the question @Sha :-). As Aleks has noted it makes no difference and this really annoys me as well... it's just that I've had to remove line breaks too many times from code and quotes where people thought they were being helpful when all they actually needed to do was click the quote or code button.

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary work around until (if?) the bug is fixed, you can just add a single `>` character in the very beginning of the paragraph (with line breaks):

```
>Line 1<br />
Line 2<br/>
Line 3<br/>
Line 4<br/>
```

Results in:

> Line 1
>   Line 2
>   Line 3
>   Line 4

Comment: Very interesting indeed.  I guess the formatting engine treats everything between two sets of two-or-more consecutive line breaks as one paragraph.  I'll keep that in mind.